# Why I can't run sbt after I installed it?

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

I followed the instruction "brew install sbt" and tried to run it using sbt. But I got this. I don't know why. Should I do some extra steps?

```
java.io.IOException: Not a directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:34)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: Not a directory
```

Comment: You should at least change dir to a project with build.scala or build.sbt file.

Answer (score 1):

First off, make sure the directory you're running sbt from contains a build definition, like `build.scala` or `build.sbt`.

It looks like sbt is trying to create a file and is being denied. Try running sbt with `sudo`. If that works, your problem lies with the run permissions and you should use `chown` to fix them.